# Unable to located Package Daphne

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I'm deploying a django app including django channels using nginx, gunicorn and daphne. But when i install daphne with **sudo apt install daphne**, it gives **E: unable to locate package daphne**.

What Should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daphne is a Python package on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/daphne/) that can be installed using pip:

```
pip install daphne
```

Comment: So isn't daphne required as a ubuntu package too? If I check installed ubuntu packages, daphne isn't there but its present in pip freeze. So would this make a difference?

Comment: Nope, you only need to install it with pip.

Comment: By the way, I'm having problems with deployment... socket connects on page load but as soon as i send a message in the chat application, the socket disconnects.. Any ideas what could be causing this?